# How do I compare a specific string to strings from a group using a loop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, strings, comparison

I want to compare members of a group of strings to an specific string. Why is this not working ?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\foreach \n in {x,Enu}{

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ test } 
 
\newcommand\x{Enu} 

\ifx\x\n
        this is $E_{\nu}$
\else
        this is not $E_{\nu}$
\fi

\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Consider using `\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\x}{\n}=0 <true>\else <false>\fi`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty to add a few instructions to your code to make it compilable. Feel free to revert.

Comment: There is also the xstring package `\IfStrEq`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\def\x{Enu}` instead `\newcommad`. The `\newcommand` does `\long\def` but `\foreach` from tikz does `\def` only. The comparison of two macros by `\ifx` results false if one is defined by `\def` and second by `\long\def`.

Answer (score 1):

`expl3` features a function called `\str_case:nn(TF)`, which is in a way the inverse of what you want, but I guess usable for you. It compares a string to a list of strings. There is also `\str_if_eq:nnTF` to just compare two strings. And we can loop over a comma separated list using `\clist_map_inline:nn`.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

% we borrow three functions from expl3
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \forclist \clist_map_inline:nn
\cs_new_eq:NN \strcaseTF \str_case:nnTF
\cs_new_eq:NN \strifeqTF \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\forclist{x,Enu,y}
  {%
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{test}
      \strcaseTF{#1}
        {
          {x}   {this is `x'}
          {Enu} {this is $E_{\nu}$}
        }
        {. One was matched.}
        {No matches found.}
    \end{frame}%
  }

\forclist{x,Enu}
  {%
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{test2}
      \strifeqTF{#1}{Enu}{this is $E_{\nu}$}{this is not $E_{\nu}$}%
    \end{frame}%
  }
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to stick to `\foreach` (because it can do more than `\clist_map_inline:nn` with its handy `...` syntax), you can use `\str_case:onTF` and `\str_if_eq:onTF` instead, which will expand the `\x` and compare its contents:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage[]{tikz}

% we borrow two functions from expl3
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \strcaseOTF \str_case:onTF
\cs_new_eq:NN \strifeqOTF \str_if_eq:onTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {x,Enu,y}
  {%
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{test}
      \strcaseOTF\x
        {
          {x}   {this is `x'}
          {Enu} {this is $E_{\nu}$}
        }
        {. One was matched.}
        {No matches found.}
    \end{frame}%
  }

\foreach\x in {x,Enu}
  {%
    \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{test2}
      \strifeqOTF\x{Enu}{this is $E_{\nu}$}{this is not $E_{\nu}$}%
    \end{frame}%
  }
\end{document}
```